# How to zoom an image using DCT transform

Tags: image-processing, dct

I am familiar with zoom using fourrier transform on an Image.
I am also aware that DCT is used mainly to compress images.
Meanwhile, how can someone use this transform to zoom an image?

Comment: Could you please provide more insights on which "Fourier zoom" you are talking about?

Comment: And be aware that there are several types of DCT (which might not be an issue here)

Comment: Mainly I am using fast fourrier transfor (using FFT2 command in matlab)

Answer (score 1):

The following IEEE pdf discusses image **interpolation** (aka zooming) by DCT. Have a look at [it](http://ieeexplore.ieee.org/iel1/2220/4213/00161259.pdf) 
The main idea remains the same: the DCT spectra is **zero padded** and converted back into time to obtain the interpolated image which yields the zooming effect.

Comment: @damdam092 have you seen the paper ?